# Feeding data to Haskell twice function as explained by Erik Meijer lecture 7

Tags: function, haskell

Can somebody point me to how to feed data to:

```
twice f x = f (f x)
```

It's taken from Erik Meijer's lecture, and I have the feeling I can only truely understand when passing data to it. Now this only results in errors.

Comment: Adding 1 to 2 twice is `twice (1+) 2`.

Comment: "Now this only results in errors." -> what do you mean? What have you tried? Which error do you get?

Comment: Perhaps compare to `once f x = f x`, where `once` is more commonly spelled `($)`. Also, `twice f = f . f` or `twice f = (.) f f`, which leads to the minimal (and unreadable) definition `twice = join (.)`

Comment: @gallais: most comments helped me out, but I need to explain you what the error was. My biggest mistake I was feeding {twice} values rather than a function and an argument. So I got confused. Comments of all of you got me on track again, so I will dig some deeper into the wonderful world of Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

The derived type signature is `(t -> t) -> t -> t`. Pass any arguments that match and you won't get compiler errors. One example is `twice (+1) 0`.

Answer (score 1):

The main mistake here is disregarding the type of `twice`. In Haskell types are very important, and explain precisely how you would call such a function.

```
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

So, the function works in this way:

- the caller chooses any type `a` they want
- the caller passes a function `f` of type `a -> a`
- the caller passes an argument of type `a`
- `twice` finally produces a value of type `a`

Hence, we could do the following. We can choose, for instance, `a = Int`. Then define the function `f` as

```
myFun :: Int -> Int
myFun y = y*y + 42
```

then choose `x :: Int` as `10`. Finally, we can make the call

```
twice myFun 10
```

Alternatively, we can use a lambda and skip the function definition above

```
twice (\y -> y*y + 42) 10
```

Answer (score 0):

For illustration here are three functions called erik1, erik2, and erik3 with the same type signature.

```
erik1, erik2, erik3  ::(a  ->  a)  ->  a  ->  a 
erik1 f x = f x
erik2 f x = f(f x)  -- Equivalent to "twice"
erik3 f x = f(f(f x))
```

These eriks take two arguments, the first being a function and the second being a number. Let's choose sqrt as the function and the number to be 16 and run the three eriks.  Here's what you get:

```
*Main> erik1 sqrt 16
4.0
*Main> erik2 sqrt 16
2.0
*Main> erik3 sqrt 16
1.4142135623730951
```

There are many things you can try, such as erik3 (/2) 16 = 2,because the f in the function allows you to use any appropriate function. In the particular case of sqrt, erik3 is equivalent to this statement in C:

```
printf ("Eighth root of 16 =  %f \n", sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(16))));
```

[Dr. Meijer Ch 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRTQkBO2v-s&list=PLlHF8jw6FqhBKWxhfZchP0haXXPYk5mSB&index=7)  1:48 to 3:37
As I watched this lecture last night a key point was made when Erik wrote the type signature as twice :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a) and said, "**twice is a function that takes a to a and returns a new function from a to a**, and by putting some extra parens it becomes painfully obvious that twice is a higher order function."

A C example that comes closer to illustrating that is:

```
#define eighthRoot(x)  (sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(x))))
printf ("eigthtRoot(16)  = %f \n", eighthRoot(16));
```